# Animate or Move image from right to left

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am writing this code to move image left to right, and it working fine.
But, now I want to do this from right to left.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:20.0
delay:0.0
options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction + UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat +UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
animations:^{imageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, 12000, 768); 
}
completion:nil];
```

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **X-Coordinate** of  your image view frame.

Use below

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:20.0
delay:0.0
options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction + UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat +UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
animations:^{imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 12000, 768); 
}
completion:nil];
```

Comment: Fun tip: you can also make CGRects as follows: (CGRect){.origin.x = 0, .size.width = 12000, .size.height = 768} whee!

Comment: @Andrew Pouliot  : I have already mentioned the same CGRect in my answer :)

Comment: I'm just being a C99 fan, ok.